# How to set indent only return key with php-mode in emacs

Tags: php, emacs, indentation

I installed `php-mode` from https://github.com/ejmr/php-mode.

With this mode I need to hit `TAB` to make indentation like this.

```
if (conditon){ # Hit `return`
| <- cursor stays here.
}

if (conditon){ # Hit `return`
    | <- I want to set cursor hier without hitting `TAB`.
}
```

I think if I re-define key bind for `RET` then cursor moves as I expected, but I don't know how to write it. Can somebody help me?

Comment: I didn't ask about key binding, but about the indentation.

Comment: "I think if I re-define key bind for RET then cursor moves as I expected, but I don't know how to write it. Can somebody help me?"

Comment: I asked about function `newline-and-indent` that I didn't know. That's why I didn't know how to write it.

Comment: My previous comment was a bit facetious. The important thing is that the two questions are trying to solve the exact same problem (and indeed accepted very similar answers). The fact the the phrasing of the question was a little different doesn't really matter -- when the same problem is solved more than once, it's valuable to link the questions together as duplicates so that anyone who finds one of them will see the other as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```lisp
(eval-after-load "php-mode"
  '(define-key php-mode-map (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it works fine! The last parentase is not necessary though.

Comment: @Tetsu Second parenthesis closing eval-after-load needed by this. Without eval-after-load you'll get an error from init, if php-mode-map isn't there already.

Comment: @Andreas The answer is edited after I posted the comment. The first line was not there.

Answer (score 2):

You want to enable `electric-indent-mode`.

Comment: Lucas Eduardo: It appears to provide a perfectly good answer to the question (for Emacs >= 24.1). Why do you feel otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

The function you want, `newline-and-indent`, is by default bound to <kbd>C-j</kbd> instead of <kbd>RET.</kbd>

So you could either just start using <kbd>C-j</kbd> (which I did because I found those keys actually easier to access than <kbd>RET</kbd>), or redefine RET with either the `define-key` line from the other answer, or alternatively a `local-set-key` in the `php-mode-hook` like this:

```
(defun set-ret-to-newline-and-indent ()
  (local-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent))
(add-hook 'php-mode-hook 'set-ret-to-newline-and-indent)
```